# jQuery - Reset var / Refresh var on window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, window, refresh, var

I'm working with a jQuery plugin that has this:

```
var $el  = $(this),

$wrapper = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),

$items   = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),

cache    = {};

// save the with of one item    

cache.itemW      = $items.width();

// save the number of total items

cache.totalItems = $items.length;
```

My problem here is that the div's width that I need to get is fluid: it's a 33% of it's wrapper. The plugin works nice when the page loads, but breaks really ugly when the window is resized.

I think that what I need is to get the vars again on resize, unless you can think of a better alternative.

Here's a link to the WIP: http://arielodiz.com.ar/test/ (scroll down to the 'portfolio')

This is the original plugin: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin makes the DIV absolute positionned and does not refresh the positions on resize automatically.

A quick solution (not a good one though) is to init the plugin again on window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel({
        scroll : 2
    });
});
```

---

A better solution would be to bind the resize event in the init method of the plugin itself - maybe adding an option to control it - to re-do the calculation and re-position the elements when the window is resized.

Depending on the browser, the resize event fires multiple times or only when the resize is done, so I use a timeout of 150ms that will make the re-calc when the mouse supposedly stopped moving...

Here's the code to add in the init method (see the fiddle for the correct place).

```
var resizeTimer;
// bind the resize event of the window
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // re-select the items in the order they are now
        var $elements = $wrapper.children('.ca-item');
        // re-calc the width
        cache.itemW = $elements.width();
        // change position accordingly
        $elements.each(function(i) {
            $(this).css({
                left: i * cache.itemW + 'px'
            });
        });
    }, 150);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/tFLqQ/)**

Comment: I tried that already, but the plugin creates many elements, and if I just initiate it again and again it overpopulates.

Comment: unless there was a way to 'undo' the plugin's results befor initiating it again.

Comment: I just needed some minutes to make the better solution, have a look. You could also add an option to plugin to make it by default re-position on window resize.

Comment: Well the plugin caches the width in the init method and uses this cached value. It has to be done a bit differently. I'll think of something else and come back to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I couldn't manage to make it work with the last update, probably my bad. Let's see what you come back with and if that doesn't do it I guess i'll have to give up and build it differently.

Thanks A LOT again!

Comment: I've updated my answer. For the timeout, it might not be necessary, just try it with or without.